# Movie with line "Remember the word Yahoo"

Tags: story-identification

Does anyone remember the name of a movie where there are two guys that are friends in the present and one had a family and was struggling financially. The friend goes back into the past (don't remember how or why) and while he is there meets his other friend as a young boy and tells him to "remember the word Yahoo".  When he gets back to the present his friend has invested in Yahoo stocks and done well.  It was only a side story of the real story but all I can remember about the movie.

Comment: The "Frequency" answer is correct, but the main character does not go back into the past - he can communicate with his family in the past via their ham radio.

Answer (score 16):

**Frequency** released in 2000 has this as a quote, and it's given to a friend so that he can invest.

> "I want you to remember this word, okay? It's kind of like a code word: Yahoo. Can you remember that?"

[IMDB link](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0186151/)

> It revolves around a radio that reaches 30 years into the past to talk to his dad, and is used to help solve a serial murder.

Comment: “I also want you to remember to sell before 2001. And back up any data you add to Upcoming.org once they buy it.”